# Firefox 40 does not allow the extension even after signing

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, nss, xpi

I am Using Firefox 40 and followed [Signing an XPI](https://www.mozdevgroup.com/docs/pete/Signing-an-XPI.html) article to sign an XPI. Used certutil to sign the XPI, imported the X509.cacert in firefox Certificate Manager (Authorities tab) every step completed as mentioned in the article. Now if I install the XPI , I get popup.

> Caution: This site would like to install an unverified add-on in Firefox

After installation the extension is working correctly.

However if I set the flag: xpinstall.signature.required  to true  and then try to install it . I get popup telling

> This add-on could not be installed as it appears to be corrupt.

Followed the steps in the article multiple times just to make sure I din't miss anything ..but still the same issue. Would appreciate any pointers to where to look for the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extensions now have to be signed by mozilla unless you're using nightly/dev edition or a special unbranded release/beta builds.

See [this page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Addons/Extension_Signing#Timeline) for further information.

If you want to distribute them yourself AMO should have an option to submit extensions for signing without listing them.

Comment: Is there any way to sign with a  third party trusted authority (Verisign) and not have to go through AMO ?

Comment: *any* way? well, you probably could compile your own firefox build that uses a versign root cert to verify extensions. but i think  using the unbranded builds would be easier in that case.

Comment: Thinking of it, the devs also mentioned something about considering adding something for corporate users in the esr releases, maybe a way to add custom certificates. But I haven't heard of concrete plans yet. The next esr with signature checking is still off in the future.

Comment: Thanks @the8472 . I ll try out AMO and see how feasible it is for internal applications.