# Selenium IDE Add On blocked

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, updates

After the latest security update for Firefox, the add-on for Selenium IDE was disabled and I cant enable it again.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox 40 does not allow the extension even after signing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521758/firefox-40-does-not-allow-the-extension-even-after-signing)